# Screen resolution twice smaller than it actually is

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

The issue I'm facing is quite strange to say the least. I don't even know what to test anymore because I don't know what's causing this problem.

**Testing from an iMac ( 5120 x 2880 )**

- media queries work properly
- typing $(window).width() in console return the correct width;

**Testing on a macbook pro ( 1920 x 1080 )**

- Viewing website in fullscreen (1920) show tablet layout (max-width: 1024px)
- typing $(window).width() in console returns 960px ( the actual width divided by 2 )

The website uses jquery 2.1.1, bootstrap 3.3.5, and some custom css and js files. I've removed them one by one still no difference.

It's worth mentioning that on the macbook pro I'm only facing this issue on Chrome. Tested on Safari and works as expected. All other websites in Chrome look just fine ( so can't be a browser issue? ).

The client just said she's facing the same issue on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the macbook a retina display ?

If yes,you have to mention it in the CSS in order to have correct calculations.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: I read about the retina display media queries however this is not the case here. This problem happens on a Windows machine as well and bootstrap also detects the screen to be 2 times smaller.